# LibVLC C# WPF MediaPlayer Audio exception

Tags: c#, libvlc

Trying to play video with LibVLC (VLCdotnet) and the MediaPlayer/Audio/All property gives this error. Anyone who met something like this? Any help would be appreciated.

> '((Vlc.DotNet.Core.AudioOutputsManagement)((Vlc.DotNet.Core.AudioManagement)mediaPlayer.Audio).Outputs).All' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException'

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"E:\Statisfying.mp4");

        var currentDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        // Default installation path of VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows
        var libDirectory =
            new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC");

        using (var mediaPlayer = new Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcMediaPlayer(libDirectory))
        {
            var mediaOptions = new[]
            {
                ":sout =#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,acodec=vorb,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:http{mux=ogg,dst=:8080/}",
                ":sout-all",
                ":sout-keep"
            };

            mediaPlayer.SetMedia(file, mediaOptions);

            mediaPlayer.Play();

            Console.WriteLine("Streaming on http://localhost:8080");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this with latest VLC version? I have played it successfully - the main problem is the compatibility. All their API-s are changed after 1-2 years and you have to re-write the app or work with older VLC. PS: compile your EXE as `x86`, not AnyCPU.

Comment: Well, it's downloaded with the NuGet Package manager, but also tried from the installed VLC folder. Compiled to x86.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with Vlc.DotNet 3.0 ? (which is still a prerelease as time of writing).

A lot of improvements and bugfixes have been made to the 3.0 version.

Comment: Well, thanks! Have tried, but still says at MediaPlayer -> Audio -> Outputs property, that "Not implemented in LibVLC".

Comment: You're probably referring to the "Current" property of AudioOutputsManagement. You can see at https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/blob/develop/src/Vlc.DotNet.Core/AudioOutputsManagement.cs that this property is write only. Libvlc doesn't provide a way to get this info.